# SQLITE3, Request/Update Row by Row

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to check in a sql-table some conditions (row by row) and if a condition is given, then update a specific column in that row with a value.

The table looks like this:

```
sql_instruction = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weather (
        "Value1" REAL,
        "Data1" REAL,
        "Param1" REAL,
        "Data2" REAL,
        "Param2" REAL,
        "Data3" REAL,
        "Param3" REAL,
        "TotalParam" REAL,
        "MAX" REAL,
        "MIN" REAL,
        "startdate" REAL,
        "enddate" REAL
        ); """
cursor.execute(sql_instruction)
connection.commit()
```

I want to retrieve the "endate" of a row where TotalParam = 0, calculate with a value from another table the MAX and MIN (no problem with that), calculate some other stuff and then update the output of the calculations for Param1, Param2, Param3  and TotalParam = Param1+Param2+Param3

My approach (for MAX) was:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM weather")
lenght_table = cursor.fetchone()[0]
print('lenght of table: 'lenght_table)

for t in lenght_table:
    cursor.execute("SELECT enddate100 FROM weather WHERE TotalParam = 0 AND rowid BETWEEN ? AND ?", ([t-1], [t]))
    intermed_preddate100 = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    intermed_preddate100 = datetime.datetime.strptime(intermed_preddate100, dformat)
    cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(close) from weatherdata WHERE Date BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY Date", (intermed_preddate100, ldate_reg))
    compare_max_reg100 = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    compare_max_reg100 = float(compare_max_reg100)
```

I know that this is not working for the retrieving part, but maybe anyone of you has an idea how to overcome this obstacle I´m trying to solve since a week...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I Dont fully understand your program logic, but maybe simply would work:

```
UPDATE weather SET TotalParam = Param1+Param2+Param3, Param1='something' where TotalParam = 0 and <something else>
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for your understanding:
1. Step: Retrieve the data "enddate" from the table where "TotalParam" = 0 for the first row where this is the case
2. Step: Calculate something with that data
3. Input the outcome of the calculation in the same row where step1 took the data from (but another column)

Comment: `select _rowid_, EndDate, Param1, Param2 from weather where TotalParam = 0` and you have exact rows ( `_rowid_` ) in sqlite what records should be updated. And you could use `update` sentence ending with .... `where "_rowid_" in (list_of__rowid_s)` if calculation (of step 2) can be performed in SQL sentence

Comment: I will try this today and give a feedback asap.! The calculation will be done in python, because it´s a forecast with a couple of regression-analysis-calculations. But your remark gives me a hint how to approach this!

Comment: Maybe `WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM weather ORDER BY rowid ASC LIMIT 1)` will be helpful as well